# openssl hangs after first output

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to check the certificate using the openssl's s_client command, and for some reason it hangs in the first line of the output.

Here is the command I am using and the output:

`[root@pr-logcollector-a ~]# openssl s_client -connect 10.95.190.13:8089
CONNECTED(00000003)

`

Why it hangs in this step? and what can I do to solve this issue?

I have tried the same command on deferent server that I have and it spets out all the data I need.
Also I have checked the firewall and all the ports are allowed.

Comment: What exactly is running at 10.95.190.13:8089? Without knowing precisely what you're trying to connect to, I'm not sure how we could tell you how to properly connect to it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz
That's my Splunk license master, I'm trying to connect one of the Splunk components to the Splunk license master, but I'm not able to.

Comment: (1) add `-debug -state` to show in detail what the client is sending and receiving (2) if, as I guess, client sends ClientHello and receives _nothing_, get a network trace (wireshark, tcpdump, or similar) to see if the system is receiving no packets, some (but not all), or all, and if less than all another at the server to see what it is _sending; if server is sending packets but client is not receiving complain to whoever runs your network; if server is not sending complain to whoever runs the server.